# What is the best way to implement role-based security in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, security-roles

The site I'm working on is mid-sized, 3 developers, a few thousand users, and is very critical to the small business running it.  So what I'm getting at is, this is not a Fortune 500 company, but is a serious enterprise needing to implement role-based security in a time/budget efficent way that is still pretty simple to use and has a high-degree of security.

The site will praimrily be custom coded, but we want to efficiently leverage components wherever we can.  There will be about 6 roles (buyer, seller, admin, partner, etc.), most will be external users so we anticipate a form where they enter uername, pw, etc.  We'll most likely store user info in a SQL Server table.

I'd like your thoughts on the best technology to use for role-based security, hopefully based on your real-world experience.

Answer (score 2):

This is your [best bet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479032.aspx). I also suggest you look into the [provider model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479030.aspx) as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Give a look to the [SqlRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998314.aspx), I've used it successfully with the Sql and ActiveDirectory [Membership Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx).